# Select to Return Multiple Rows from Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am working on a query that returns a list of items shown below:

```
SELECT ID, Description FROM TableA WHERE ID = 10001
```

Returns:

```
ID     Description
10001  Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
```

However, what I want is to be able to make the return multiple rows.

```
ID     Description
10001  Item1 
10001  Item2 
10001  Item3 
10001  Item4
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: this makes no sense to me! how are your data stored? do you have 4 different records with ID=10001? if so, then this select SHOULD return 4 rows. it wouldn't combine them in 1.

Comment: If you've found *any* way, easy or hard, I would suggest that method to definitely split the data and store it like that, on multiple rows, with one master record and multiple detail records for the items.

Comment: I would suggest making a function that splits them using a space as a delimiter.

Comment: Best way is to normalize your tables and relations.

Comment: Some kind people have already provided you with technical solutions, but as some of the comments above are trying to say, you are doing it wrong! It is misusing the database to store multiple values (items) within a column (description). The whole point of a database is to make your data accessible. What if you wanted only the id's where the item = "ABC"? You would again need convoluted processing. Please reconsider your design, and store the data as in your "what I want", with ID repeated and one item per row.

Comment: u have my sympathy. u probably just stuck in someone else's bad design. however, judging from ur gold badges, i think u can easily find many existing solution accross the web.

Comment: i do understand your concerns. but i am just stuck with this legacy design. i just started work a couple of months ago and this is what they currently have. i would change the design but that means altering the way millions of records are being kept. anyway, thank you all for the help! i really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
SELECT id,
   Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
FROM  (SELECT id, CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(description, ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS n from TableA where id = 1001) AS A 
CROSS APPLY n.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/152e3/1

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a function to do that as such

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RowToManyRows] ( @StringInput VARCHAR(8000) )
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(10) )
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(10)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                                ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                                LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @StringInput), 0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [String] )
        VALUES ( @String )
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```

You then query that function as such

```
SELECT ID, String
FROM myTable CROSS APPLY [dbo].RowToManyRows(myTable.Description)
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable 
( ID INT, 
   Description VARCHAR(50)
 )

 INSERT INTO dbo.myTable
         ( ID, Description )
 VALUES  ( 1, -- ID - int
           'A B'  -- Description - varchar(50)
         ),
         (2, 
         'C D')
```

Results

```
1   A
1   B
2   C
2   D
```